# Stop cmd window from closing automatically

Tags: windows, cmd, console-application, pascal

I use Dev-Pascal on Windows 8.
When I run the program, cmd.exe opens and runs the program and closes automatically.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: prevent what? opening or closing?

Comment: prevent closing automatically

Answer (score 1):

Try to add  `readln;` before `end.`

This will make your program to pause till you hit enter.

Comment: fixed for the great justice

Comment: Thank you for answer. ya I usually define an additional var in the program and use Readln. But, I need a comprehensive solution.

Comment: Console programs are designed that way. But you might run it *from* cmd , it won't close after your app is finished.