# Lazarus Pascal Code not working properly cmd screen closes immediately

Tags: pascal, lazarus

this is my pascal code how good it looks but not working properly.
It closes directly when it should print the latest output to the screen.

```
Uses crt;

label durak1;

var      
  yas: Integer;

begin
  durak1:
  CLRSCR;
  write('YASINIZI BELIRTINIZ : '); READLN(yas);

  if (yas <0) or (yas >150 ) then begin 
    writeln('LUTFEN GECERLI BIR YAS ARALIGI GIRINIZ');
    delay(2000); 
    goto durak1;
  end;

  case yas of
    0,1:      writeln('Bebek Yas Grubu'); 
    2..5:     writeln('Cocuk Yas Grubu');
    6..18:    writeln('Genc Yas Grubu'); 
    19..34:   writeln('Orta Yas Grubu');
    35..59:   writeln('Hafif Yasli Grubu');
    60..100:  writeln('Bi Ayagi Cukurda Yas Grubu');
    101..150: writeln('Olmus Yas Grubu');
    else      
      writeln('Yanlis Tuslama');
      delay(10000); 
      goto durak1;
  end;
end.
```

this is code easy because I try to repeat what I saw at school

Comment: So it prints some output and then the program ends. Sounds like the program behaves exactly as expected.

Comment: @Samet: Have you ever tried to press Win+R, type `ipconfig`, and then Enter? Does this mean that the `ipconfig` application is broken?

Comment: There is a ReadLn, so it should not close.

Comment: please use search function
[Stop cmd window from closing automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619602/stop-cmd-window-from-closing-automatically)

Comment: @dwrbudr: Not after the "Hafif Yasli Grubu", which I guess is an example of "the latest output to the screen".

Comment: You have not understood console programs yet: none of them needs to pause before it ends. You have not understood debugging yet: put a breakpoint on `end.` to pause your program right before it _literally_ ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lacking additional `ReadLN` call when the user enters the valid age. Right now there is no `ReadLN` call after your case statement and therefore your application closes as soon as user enters valid age.

```
Uses crt;

label durak1;

var      
  yas: Integer;

begin
  durak1:
  CLRSCR;
  write('YASINIZI BELIRTINIZ : '); READLN(yas);

  if (yas <0) or (yas >150 ) then begin 
    writeln('LUTFEN GECERLI BIR YAS ARALIGI GIRINIZ');
    delay(2000); 
    goto durak1;
  end;

  case yas of
    0,1:      writeln('Bebek Yas Grubu'); 
    2..5:     writeln('Cocuk Yas Grubu');
    6..18:    writeln('Genc Yas Grubu'); 
    19..34:   writeln('Orta Yas Grubu');
    35..59:   writeln('Hafif Yasli Grubu');
    60..100:  writeln('Bi Ayagi Cukurda Yas Grubu');
    101..150: writeln('Olmus Yas Grubu');
    else      
      writeln('Yanlis Tuslama');
      delay(10000); 
      goto durak1;
  end;
  //Add another READLN call here to prevent application from closing instantly when valid age is entered
  READLN(yas);
end.
```

I recommend you learn how to use breakpoints and step through your code in order to observe your code flow. Knowing how to observe your code execution step by step is very important. Because this is the only way to make sure your code is executing the way you want it to.

Comment: Well, adding a `ReadLn` might not be a good idea. What if `ping` forced you to press Return before returning to the command processor? IMHO, it would be better to advise the OP to start his or her application from the command line. One may use a `ReadLn` as a temporary debugging tool, though.

Comment: my code is working now.Thanks for your help.i realized where i went wrong

Comment: Quite often IDEs (or projects) have some option to keep the screen around.